# What's causing kernel panic on mid 2011 iMac? (a freed zone element has been modified)

Tags: imac, kernel-panic

I've got a mid 2011 iMac that kernel panics roughly after 30 to 45mins of being powered on. Then the panics seem to get worst eg after every restart of the imac.

I've tried x2 different boot drives both using OS X 10.10.5 as the base system, one being a USB drive and other being a thunderbolt drive.

At the moment my theories are it's more of a hardware problem then software, either ram or possible gpu.

See screenshot of report below:
[image: report_imac]

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the text of the Panic error?  This will allow the site to search on the error text and help other users if they have the same, or similar, errors.  `mdworker` is the Spotlight thread.

Comment: Yes, we need the full text, as text, not as a picture. However, from just the screenshot itself, first suspect is 'shapeservices.msm.driver' & any other 3rd party kexts you have installed.

Comment: Looks like the crash was about 2 min's after the AppleHWSensor driver was loaded, if I'm reading that correctly.  Maybe RAM-related?

Comment: Have you run apple hardware test?

Comment: I will run apple hardware test in morning

Comment: I will try to obtain full text report, but currently iMac is powering off on boot up with x2 different boot drives.

Comment: I will check ram & removed ram and report back.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be one piece of bad ram installed in the iMac.